# Swift: get array from JSON encoded data

Tags: arrays, json, swift

I have a JSON encoded data which I download using GCD. You can see how the JSON is encoded from this link: https://quiz2019.herokuapp.com/api/quizzes?token=8fda199c75cb200b0f85

I want to access every single data from that JSON but I can't achieve it. I have tried doing this:

```
let arrayData = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
```

but after this I don't know how to access every data on the array. Any idea?

Comment: The root object of the JSON is a **dictionary**, please note the `{}`. The array is the value for key `quizzes`. You are encouraged to use `Decodable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let quizzes: [Quiz]
    let pageno: Int
    let nextURL: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case quizzes, pageno
        case nextURL = "nextUrl"
    }
}

struct Quiz: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let question: String
    let author: Author?
    let attachment: Attachment
    let favourite: Bool
    let tips: [String]
}

struct Attachment: Codable {
    let filename: String
    let mime: MIME
    let url: String
}

enum MIME: String, Codable {
    case imageJPEG = "image/jpeg"
}

struct Author: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let isAdmin: Bool?
    let username: String
}
```

---

```
let roo = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self,from:jsonData)
print(roo)
```

Comment: This gives me errors saying "Use of undeclared type 'Codable' / 'CodingKey' "

Comment: I was using an old version of Xcode. I just downloaded the newest and I could use it, thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the above native solution by [Sh_khan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5820010/sh-khan) (as native solutions are always best and fast)
or 
an alternative solution is that you can use [Object Mapper](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/ObjectMapper).

It is the one of the best json parsing library and very easy.
Just write a single line:-

```
let user = Mapper<User>().map(JSONString: JSONString)
```

You can use [Json Export](https://github.com/Ahmed-Ali/JSONExport) for converting your json into model.

Hope it helps :)